# Node.js : difference between Buffer.slice and Buffer.subarray

Tags: node.js, buffer

I have a look at the Node.js Buffer documentation and I don't understand the difference between [Buffer.slice](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end) and [Buffer.subarray](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_subarray_start_end).

Both point to "the same memory as the original".

But no one seems not to be the alias of the other (it seems to be said when it is the case).

And test says that behavior is the same :

```
> buf=Buffer.from([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
<Buffer 00 01 02 03 04 05 06>
> bufSlice=buf.slice(1,5)
<Buffer 01 02 03 04>
> bufSub=buf.subarray(1,5)
<Buffer 01 02 03 04>
> bufSlice
<Buffer 01 02 03 04>
> bufSub
<Buffer 01 02 03 04>
> buf[3]=0xff
255
> buf
<Buffer 00 01 02 ff 04 05 06>
> bufSub
<Buffer 01 02 ff 04>
> bufSlice
<Buffer 01 02 ff 04>
```

(even if example of slice in Node.js documentation is not very clear).

So what's the difference ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but here is an interesting read on performance between the 2: [https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/17431](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/17431). It seems they achieve the same results; they are destructive methods that change the memory address values, but their implementations differ because their prototype is `Uint8Array.prototype.slice()` and `TypedArray.prototype.subarray()`

Comment: According to [this blog post](http://shockry.blogspot.com/2017/04/javascript-typed-arrays-slice-vs.html) only the `subArray` method is referencing to the same chunk in memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Buffer.slice`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/buffer.html#bufslicestart-end) is now deprecated (since node 16.x LTS)

So now use [`Buffer.subarray`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufsubarraystart-end) !

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question whether subarray is the same or not as slice in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 5):

For a NodeJS `Buffer` there is no difference and indeed `Buffer.slice()` is deprecated now so you should use `Buffer.subarray()`.

This deprecation was presumably done because NodeJS `Buffer.slice()` was inconsistent with other `slice` calls in JS, e.g.:

```
const t = Buffer.from([1])
t.slice()[0]=2
console.log(t[0]) // logs 2, i.e. `slice` uses same underlying memory, like `subarray` does

const t2 = [1]
t2.slice()[0]=2
console.log(t2[0]) // logs 1, unchanged! I.e. `slice` copied underlying memory

const t3 = new Uint8Array([1])
t3.slice()[0]=2
console.log(t3[0]) // logs 1, unchanged! I.e. `slice` copied underlying memory
```

Comment: my example tells both are references.

Comment: hope my edit cleared things up

Answer (score 0):

According to https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufsubarraystart-end, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/slice,

`Buffer.subarray()` is a buffer view that does not need to create an extra copy of the underlying buffer. This makes `subarray()` much more efficient than `slice()`, which does create a copy.

Comment: According to https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufslicestart-end:

"This method is not compatible with the Uint8Array.prototype.slice(), which is a superclass of Buffer. To copy the slice, use Uint8Array.prototype.slice()."

So `Buffer.slice()` does not behave like the link to `TypedArray.slice()`